# Select another table in join query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 table.

1. stock

   - `stock_id (PK)`
   - `barang_id(FK)`
2. Stock_invoice

   - `stock_invoice_id(PK)`
   - `stock_id(FK)`
   - `invoice_id(FK)`
3. Barang

   - `barang_id(PK)`
   - `stock_id(FK)`
   - `name_barang`

I want to display the stock data that has not been entered into the stock_invoice table. Then I write the query as follows

`SELECT a.stock_id,a.barang_id, b.stock_invoice_id
FROM stock a
LEFT JOIN stock_invoice b ON a.stock_id=b.stock_id
WHERE b.stock_id IS NULL`

but i have problem how to select `name_barang` of Barang table

Comment: Why is `stock_id` and `barang_id` in both e `Stock` and `Barang` tables?  (Sorry, but I don't know the word `Barang`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
SELECT a.stock_id,a.barang_id,c.name_barang,b.stock_invoice_id
FROM stock a
LEFT JOIN stock_invoice b ON a.stock_id=b.stock_id
LEFT JOIN Barang c  ON a.barang_id=c.barang_id 
WHERE b.stock_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to join third table

```
SELECT a.stock_id,c.name_barang, b.stock_invoice_id
FROM stock a
LEFT JOIN stock_invoice b ON a.stock_id=b.stock_id
JOIN barang c ON a.barang_id = c.barang_id 
WHERE b.stock_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a three way join,

```
SELECT 
      a.stock_id,
      a.barang_id,
      b.stock_invoice_id,
      c.name_barang 
    FROM
      stock a 
      LEFT JOIN stock_invoice b 
        ON a.stock_id = b.stock_id 
      JOIN Barang c 
        ON a.barang_id = c.barang_id 
    WHERE b.stock_id IS NULL
```